# awk で複数の separator を一塊としてみなすかどうかは何で決まる？

Tags: awk

`,` を区切り文字にした場合と、 (空白) を区切り文字にした場合で `awk` の挙動が異なることに気がつきました。

具体的には、空白の場合には複数の空白文字をひとつの区切りとして取り扱いますが、 `,` の場合には、`,` が連続していてもそれぞれの文字が別々の区切りとして取り扱われています。

この挙動の差異は、何によって決定されていますか？具体的には、どの文字だと一塊区切りになり、どの文字だと別々区切りになりますか？

スクリプト例:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf 'a,,,b\n' | awk -F, '{print $2}'
# => output empty

printf 'a   b\n' | awk '{print $2}'
# => output b

printf 'a   b\n' | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'
# => output b

printf 'a   b\n'
# => output a   b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

空白一文字を与えた場合には特別な扱いとなり、行頭と行末の空白文字は削除されて、1個以上の空白がFSになります。より詳しくは、[POSIXのドキュメント](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) や `man awk` を参照してみてください。

Comment: 空白１文字だけが、ピンポイントで特殊処理なのですね。。

Answer (score 0):

gawk ですが… `-F` は正規表現を受け付けますので次のようにすれば `,` と同様の動作になりました。

```
$ printf 'a   b\n' | awk -F' {1}' '{print $2}'
```

これから推測すると、`-F' '` の場合は空白文字の繰返しの正規表現に内部的に置き換わってるのかなという気がします。

Comment: posix ドキュメントに、「空白１文字だけ特殊扱いだよ」と書いてありました。(正規表現で空白１文字をどうにかして表しても、それはその他と同じ扱いっぽいです。)